# How can I check if the type of my variable passed to template function is a string? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, templates

I am writing a single template function that returns a specific string depending on the type of the variable passed to it. Specifically, I am wondering how to check if that type is a string or not, and also, whether it is a string just containing the number "1".

I am having trouble using *typeid* with determining the variable passed is a string or not.

I have tried this solution, then returned new strings regarding the condition.

```
if ((typeid(variable) == typeid(std::string)) && (variable == "1"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Rather use a template specialization.

Answer (score 2):

Since `T` has to be known at compile-time in order for the compiler to generate code for `(a_variable == "1")`, to use `typeid()` the way you are will require you to explicitly type-cast `a_variable` to access its value at runtime (think of what code the compiler tries to generate for `(a_variable == "1")` when `a_variable` is not a `std::string`), eg:

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
std::string the_type(T a_variable) {
    std::string r_string;

    if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)) {
        if (reinterpret_cast<std::string&>(a_variable) == "1") {
            r_string = "a string containing 1";
        } else {
            r_string = "just a string";
        }
    }

    ...
  
    return r_string;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/oq70Ne)

In C++17 and later, you can use `if constexpr` instead to perform type-checks of template parameters at compile-time using [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), no type-cast needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::string the_type(T a_variable) {
    std::string r_string;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        if (a_variable == "1") {
            r_string = "a string containing 1";
        } else {
            r_string = "just a string";
        }
    }

    ...
  
    return r_string;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ByTmjNcUw)

Otherwise, just use template specialization instead:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string the_type_helper(T) {
    return "not a string";
}
 
template <>
std::string the_type_helper<std::string>(std::string a_variable) {
    if (a_variable == "1") {
        return "a string containing 1";
    } else {
        return "just a string";
    }
}
 
template <typename T>
std::string the_type(T a_variable) {
    std::string r_string;
 
    r_string = the_type_helper<T>(a_variable);
 
    ...

    return r_string;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Auioqk)

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic type error in this line:

```
if ((typeid(variable) == typeid(std::string)) && (variable == "1"))
```

When you say `(variable == "1")`, you are telling the compiler to verify if the entire string you inserted is equal to the char `1`.

I would this by first asking the compiler is variable is a string and if the answer is yes, create a container to store your string and use an iteration function to go through each character to verify if you have the char `"1"`.

Comment: What I need is exactly the first point. I need to verify that the entire string is indeed equal to the char "1".

Comment: `"1"` isn't a `char`, it's a `const char[2]`

Comment: In this case, start by creating a new string with something like std::string a = "1"; and then you can do if (variable.find(a) != string::npos) std::cout << yes ; else std::cout<< no;

Comment: @pythonheadache that will check if `variable` *contains* the substring `"1"`, not check if `variable` is *equal* to the whole string `"1"`, which is what the OP wants